# CDO HELO strips special charcters resulting in relay denied

Tags: email, cdo.message

I have C++ code that utilizes CDO to send email based upon triggering events. I've included portions of the code below. The problem is that when app run on a server with embedded dashes such as SERVER-ABC-123 some mail servers at customer sites will reject the request with a 550 error for relayed denied. The HELO packet contains the server name with the dashes stripped which I think is the root cause of the problem.

Is there anyway to force CDO to include the FQDN?

Here is SMTP trace info

Client => Server: HELO SMCABUTELC03\x0d\x0a
Server => Client: 250 int2.unimax.pvt Hello sm-cabu-telc03.swna.wdpr.unimax.com [192.168.24.25], pleased to meet you\x0d\x0a
Client => Server: MAIL FROM: \x0d\x0a
Server => Client: 550 5.7.1 ... Relaying denied.  MAIL FROM: corp.2n.admin@sm-cabu-telc03.swna.wdpr.unimax.com does not end with SMCABUTELC03\x0d\x0a

```
CDO::IMessage* cdoMessage = NULL;
CDO::IConfiguration* cdoConfiguration = NULL;

cdoConfiguration->get_Fields(&cdoFields);

cdoFields->get_Item( _variant_t( cdoSendUsingMethod), &cdoField1);
cdoField1->put_Value( _variant_t( (long) CDO::cdoSendUsingPort));
cdoField1->Release();
cdoField1 = NULL;

cdoFields->get_Item( _variant_t( cdoSMTPServer), &cdoField2);
cdoField2->put_Value( _variant_t( emailHostName.gets()));
cdoField2->Release();
cdoField2 = NULL;

cdoFields->get_Item( _variant_t( cdoSMTPServerPort), &cdoField3);
cdoField3->put_Value( _variant_t( emailHostPort));
cdoField3->Release();
cdoField3 = NULL;

cdoFields->get_Item( _variant_t( cdoSMTPAuthenticate), &cdoField4);
if ( emailUserName.size() == 0 )
{
    cdoField4->put_Value( _variant_t( (long) CDO::cdoAnonymous));
}
else
{
    cdoField4->put_Value( _variant_t( (long) CDO::cdoBasic));
}
cdoField4->Release();
cdoField4 = NULL;
```